# SpringSource Roo Controller Removal

Tags: java, spring-roo, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

Environment: Windows XP, SpringSource Tool Suite 2.3.2, Roo 1.0.2.Release, Java 1.6.0_10, tc Server 6.0

I'm using the canned Roo generated code. I created an entity and associated controller. Then deleted both classes. The problem I'm seeing is the Roo created home page still shows the "Create/List" section for the deleted classes. I'm executing this within the tc Server, within Eclipse. Any ideas on how to get Roo to update the home page?

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer. I needed to manually edit WEB-INF/views/menu.jspx, removing the section related to the controller. I also noticed a subdirectory in WEB-INF/views related to the controller that I removed just to keep things clean. It seems to me Roo should do this for me, since it created the entries initially.

Comment: Roo doesn't remove these types of files because their functionality will consist entirely of custom logic provided by you, so they remain because they are not updated auto-magically.

Comment: Restarting STS might help too if you're using it.